# The shutdown command should have a warning message in the last,but it doesn't show

Tags: linux, shutdown

Well,I am trying to add some words like "you computer will turn off." after the command 'shutdown'.
But it doesn't show.what could I do?

[image]

Comment: By my reading, the question here is _Why didn't the `wall` message go out from `shutdown` when I set a 20-hour timeout?  How can I make it do so?_

Comment: (⊙o⊙)？？20h？ Actually it means turning off after 20 minutes.

Comment: shutdown -h 2 (1.41)
Shutdown scheduled for Thu 2020-04-02 01:43:15 CST, use 'shutdown -c' to cancel.
You can try it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to add more information to the generic warning, you could always combine shutdown with echo using "&&" (logical if) this way:

<strike>shutdown -h 20 && echo wall "computer will turn off"</strike>

What this does is evaluate the first part ("shutdown -h 20"); if it exits having completed successfully (i.e. returns 0), it will then execute the second part ("echo "computer will turn off""). If shutdown exits with a different value (for some reason), the second part will not be executed.

I use "&&" in many places, both in scripts & on the command line. It's very handy.

**Addendum**: As Kusalananda noted below, "echo" was the wrong command. I should have used "wall" -- which would send the message to all users logged into the system thusly:

```
shutdown -h 20 && wall "computer will turn off"
```

(It's been a long time since I've worked on a system with another person logged in doing work unrelated to my own, so I missed that detail.) And sorry for the delay in correcting msyelf.

Comment: OK ,it works. But I still have a question that some people use 【 shutdown [-h] [num] [words] 】.They can see the sentence in the last ,why can't I see it?

Comment: This would not broadcast the message to logged-on users.

Comment: Since message has been corrected, the command does now work